# What is the best way to record "ground truth" data during a simulation?

Tags: gazebo-11

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

What is the best way to record "ground truth" data during a simulation at each simulation timestep, ideally in an "exportable" format like .csv? Is there a generic approach that would work across different variables of interest (model pose, velocity, accelerations, joint states, contact forces/torques), or would each type of value require individual instrumentation/configuration?

All of the methods I've found have fallen a bit short of my expectations.

- The [record logging](http://www.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=log_filtering&cat=tools_utilities) utility works reasonably well, and can be started/stopped from the command line which is nice, but I've only been able to get `pose` data ([issue here](https://github.com/osrf/gazebo/issues/3144))
- [Gazebo's plotting utility](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G5qBaEXpkvE) has a nice intuitive interface and can export data in a .csv format, but to my knowledge doesn't have a programmatic interface for more systematic data collection, and appears to be limited to 10s of data
- [Gazebo ROS Plugins](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/tree/noetic-devel/gazebo_plugins/src) offer a number of sensor plugins (GPS, Force Torque, Joint State) that can monitor different aspects of the states of models, which could then be monitored and compiled into a data log (perhaps using something like plot juggler), but each model needs to be configured manually with multiple plugins before starting, and I'm not sure how "lock-step" the data published to ROS would be with the simulation.

Am I missing anything obvious? I feel like this should be pretty common functionality, so I am surprised that I haven't found a good existing approach. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/27642/what-is-the-best-way-to-record-%22ground-truth%22-data-during-a-simulation?/) by [shonigmann](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/47307/shonigmann/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 16 on 2021-12-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I didn't end up finding any existing functionality that did what I needed, so I ended up biting the bullet and making a plugin that logs the state information of selected joints and links to a .csv file. The plugin can be found [on github, here](https://github.com/shonigmann/gazebo_plugins/blob/main/src/gazebo_log_state.cpp) in case anyone else needs similar functionality in the future.

---

Originally posted by [shonigmann](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/47307/shonigmann/) with karma: 16 on 2021-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0